# ObservableBuffer to publish swing events

Tags: swing, scala, scala-collections, publisher

How do I make a `scala.collection.mutable.ObservableBuffer` publish swing events so that I can update my components when a buffer changes?

The confusing thing is that scala has two implementations of `Publisher`. One is `scala.collection.mutable.Publisher` and the second is `scala.swing.Publisher`. It's unfortunate that `ObservableBuffer` only extends the first type of `Publisher`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a subclass of `ObservableBuffer` that translates the events from the Scala way to the Swing way. I did that to turn an `ObservableBuffer` into a Eclipse `IObservableList`, you can check it out here: https://gist.github.com/951288

Note that it is a fast copy-paste, not everything may compile, but you get the idea.

Comment: Alright. I guess I was hoping for a slick way, but perhaps it's impossible.

Comment: My code is probably more complex than necessary for a Swing publisher; much of it is for dealing with the `ListDiffEvent` of `IObservableList` correctly. Don't forget the `override def ++=` though because of this bug: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4461

Comment: Philippe -- I am planning to just copy the source code of `ObservableBuffer` and modify all of the calls to `publish`.

Comment: @dsg Cool, so you can directly avoid reproducing bug 4461 linked above, then.